# How can i drag and adjust icon of jLabel according to mouse movements without scrollbars?

Tags: java, swing

```
  private void uploadimagebuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        JFileChooser input= new JFileChooser();
    input.setDialogTitle("upload the image");
     input.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        int returnval=input.showOpenDialog(this);
        BufferedImage image=null; 
        if(returnval==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)

         {
             java.io.File file=input.getSelectedFile();
             java.awt.image.BufferedImage bi;
             try
             {
                 image=ImageIO.read(file);

                 Label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));


             }
              catch(IOException e)
              {
                   e.printStackTrace();
              }
        this.pack();

         }
    }


private void LabelMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        jScrollPane1.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,0));
        Point location = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        Label.setAlignmentX(location.x+100);
        Label.setAlignmentY(location.y+100);
    }
```

i want to drag and adjust the position of the icon of jLabel according to mouse movements such that when user keeps the mouse pressed on icon and drags horizontal, the image also scroll itself according to mouse movements without scroll bars. i have checked autoscroll option but it is not working.
please help.

Icon placed inside scroll pane without scroll bars

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wyQD.jpg]

Comment: [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first port of call should be [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html), as `MouseInfo` really isn't the right tool for this job.

One solution might be to use a `JScrollPane`, but remove the scroll bars, the benefit of this is, it takes care of the bounds checking and component resizing for you automatically...

[image: Scroll Me]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            try {
                label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(...)));
                label.setAutoscrolls(true);
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(label, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                scrollPane.setBorder(null);
                add(scrollPane);

                MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

                    private Point origin;

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        origin = new Point(e.getPoint());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (origin != null) {
                            JViewport viewPort = (JViewport) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JViewport.class, label);
                            if (viewPort != null) {
                                int deltaX = origin.x - e.getX();
                                int deltaY = origin.y - e.getY();

                                Rectangle view = viewPort.getViewRect();
                                view.x += deltaX;
                                view.y += deltaY;

                                label.scrollRectToVisible(view);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                };

                label.addMouseListener(ma);
                label.addMouseMotionListener(ma);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

In fact, this solution is so simple, any other is just asking for trouble